Book with fairy - human girl who also has witch blood
I remember reading a book about a girl who is far but is bound to be human. Her father dies early on in the book (maybe a woodcutter). Then she unbinds herself and finds she also has witch blood. The witches in this world are hidden in a magical valley that is warded and hidden. I think the main character is trying to repair something and is needing their magical knowledge. And then I vividly remember she had this special fire that is only in certain powerful witch bloodlines.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?  What do you mean by "a girl who is far?"

@DavidW - Fae or faer, presumably.
